# Magnets without friction

Tags: electromagnetism, friction

Let's say a small magnet is attached with its South pole on to the north pole of a bigger magnet vertically.There is no friction between the magnets so this means the normal force increased due to the attraction doesn't have any effect on its tendency to fall.My question is that : Does the small magnet slide down OR Do the magnetic field lines have such a property to pull the magnet up.
Also, what changes are seen if the small magnet is attached vertically to a iron bar (frictionless again).[image: Magnets without friction]

Comment: In which direction do the poles of the magnets point?